# Quickest way to detect missing values in json or list of objects

Tags: c#, json, algorithm

I am receiving string that represents json array where each item is object and deserializing it to list of C# classes.

What's required is to find missing required values in each object.

For example if received:

```
[{"first_name":null, "last_name":"LastName"}, {"first_name":"FistName", "last_name":"LastName"}]
```

First name of very first object is missing but required, what's the best way to find it?

1. Json deserialized with Json.Net (Newton JSON)
2. I have a list of required fields.

Comment: How do you know it is required? How do you deserialize your JSON?

Comment: The easiest way would be to loop through the list after deserialisation.

Comment: @PatrickHofman string deserialized with Json.NET and I have a list of required fields

Comment: What if you parse the JSON as dictionary and then check the values against your list of required fields?

Comment: @Kris I may have up to 20K lines in the JSON, each line may contain up to 150 fields.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I thought about it but maybe exists other way to do it.

Comment: Each line is of type Person (POCO Class), Person has an IsValid() method.  You can use attributes to tag properties as required or just maintain a required property list.  There are literally a dozen ways you could implement this concept.

Comment: Then you could use a LINQ statement or ForEach loop to check for any IsValid() == false.

Comment: This JSON snippet doesn't miss `first_name`. The field is there with a `null` value. Strings are nullable, so this isn't a bad value either. If you want to validate the fields you'll have to use validation attributes on the POCO or create a JSON Schema and validate against it.